# How do I actually use a generic type in my generic service to create new objects?

Tags: c#, generics

NOTE: In order to write a reasonably short question, I create an example similar to the troubled area of my application. The actual example is more complex but the problem statement is accurate.

Say I have an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AnalysisObject
{
    public virtual AnalysisObject CreateObject(int id, string description) 
        { return null; }

    //Some other virtual methods in here
}
```

I derive some classes from it that contain behavior specific to some AnalysisObject types. For example:

```
public class HWAnalysisObject : AnalysisObject {

    public override AnalysisObject CreateObject(int id, string description) 
    {
        return new HWAnalysisObject();
    }
    //override more virtual methods to provide specific behavior        
}
```

Now, I want to write a generic service that can operate on AnalysisObjects. In this service I at some point need to create and return new subtypes of AnalysisObject. And I can't figure out how to do that.

```
public class AOService<TAnalysisObject> where TAnalysisObject : AnalysisObject
{
    public AnalysisObject FetchObject(int id)
    {
        return TAnalysisObject.CreateObject(id, "new object");            
    }
```

That does not compile, obviously:
"TAnalysisObject is a type parameter, which is not valid in this context."

Fair enough. But how can I use the properties, etc of the type that I pass in to my service so I know what kind of subclass to return? I feel like I'm missing Generics 101 here, which is fair enough because I usually use generic classes and services, I do not write them.

I could stick a method in the service that looks like this:

```
private AnalysisObject MakeAnalysisObject(int id, string description)
{
    if ( (typeof(TAnalysisObject) == typeof(HWAnalysisObject) )
    {
        return new HWAnalysisObject(id, description);
    }
    if ( (typeof(TAnalysisObject) == typeof(MMAnalysisObject) )
    {
        return new MMAnalysisObject(id, description);
    }
    //etc
}
```

But I feel that defeats the purpose of why I tried generics: now I can't just derive more AnalysisObject and have the service just able to take care of them: I have to maintain this method in the service every time I add a new type.

Comment: You need to do `where TAnalysisObject : AnalysisObject, new()` and then you will be able to create object via `new TAnalysisObject()`. BUT, you will be able to call only parameterless constructor, not your constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: Your sample code defines the problem statement but I don't think it depicts the intent appropriately. It would be great if you can provide a bit more background as to how the service will be used. Right now it seems like you plan to create a new instance of the service every time you need to use a different Analysis object. Is that accurate? Or are you looking to create a single service that can handle any type of Analysis object?

Comment: You have a method on class which creates it's own object. To call this method you first need to create an object then only you can create method CreateObject. Any reason to have such design? Creating a constructor with appropriate parameters and have factory created for this would be better design approach.

Comment: @Juan - that is a good point. The application has a service factory, so the idea would be to create a single service that can handle any type of analysis object.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - These objects did not have a create method until I ran into the problem where I had to figure out how to create these objects. So I thought well, maybe I can create them in this way. Turned out not to be helpful. I thought about having a factory instead since this does look like that kind of problem - but what I'm trying to create here is a service that can operate on all these AnalysisObjects, and when you need a new kind of AnalysisObject you just create one, that's the only place you have to do work. With a factory you have to create the object and maintain the factory.

Comment: Got it. What kind of things is the service going to do with these objects? Can it just rely on an interface to call methods or does the service need intimate knowledge of each Analysis object?

Comment: The least preferred solution to this would be to go via reflection and use Activator.CreateInstance method which take type and the constructor parameters as input and creates an instance of that type. I would avoid going that way if I can solve this problem using known design and OO concepts. Depending what your answer is to Juan's question, solution will be reflection or some other design

Comment: @Juan - it does not need intimate knowledge. This service mostly deals with persisting these objects to the database and retrieving them. So it translates between domain models and database entities. The only place where it needs a little bit of knowledge of these objects is where it has to set some enums on these objects. Each object has some sub-type like properties that are modeled with an enum. So the service need to pick the enum key out of the object when it saves it, and needs to set that enum when reads objects and creates them.

Comment: I see. Because it translates between models and entities, I don't think this service could be generic (at least not in the way you are implementing it). Have you looked at something like AutoMapper? It sounds like you need custom mapping functionality per type with some generic tooling for calls. You could also implement your own by having a dependency container that gives you the right mapping instance based on the type.

Comment: AutoMapper would be nice! I use that in smaller projects. This is part of an enormous application though, and which tools are used and where it isn't under my direct control. One of the drawbacks of large projects and large teams is having to find ways to work with what's there already. And sometimes that doesn't lend itself to elegant solutions. A dependency container would also make this easier - but again it is a mature code base where adding one isn't trivial and doing it without consulting the team at large is frowned on. That's why I really hoped I could find another way to do it.

Comment: Well, the only way you will be able to have a generic service is if the service doesn't need intimate knowledge of the objects, which unfortunately is required for construction. Another approach would be to have a generic service that looks for a class with a parameterless constructor in the loaded assemblies that is capable of mapping the requested type (presumably marked by an interface). You then have the best of both worlds, generic service and auto-mapping. All you have to do is create a new mapping class for each new AnalysisObject type.

Comment: That is true. I was hoping that I could make the objects abstract and have virtual methods that provide the service what it needs ( a couple foreign key ids to save, pretty much ) but in the end that comes back to what you're referring to - at some point I need to make objects and then I need to create mapping classes. This is too much work for this project, so I'm passing some extra parameters instead, but it is an interesting thing to try out for myself so I plan to do something simpler as a proof of concept. Thank you for adding your thoughts, it was helpful!

Comment: No problem. As an added note though, I understand the thing about overkill and time constraints but as a general rule, try to keep your persistence logic separate.

Comment: I discussed this problem with our system architect yesterday and we lamented the fact that we have some services that do too much. We really need to refactor our persistence logic into providers and layer services on top of that. But this is the kind of thing you get when your code base goes back to the late '90's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new()` constraint means your class needs to have a parameterless constructor. Then you can create a new one with `new T();`. There is no way to enforce another than the parameterless constructor though.

```
public class AOService<TAnalysisObject> where TAnalysisObject : AnalysisObject, new()
{
    public AnalysisObject FetchObject(int id)
    {
        return new TAnalysisObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gives the technical answer for the question I had originally. I tried this and it worked fine for my immediate problem, though it meant I had to implement additional setters on the derived objects.